# What would happen to clouds that existed in the upper atmosphere?

Tags: astronomy, weather

I am trying to determine, on a planet with extreme weather, the conditions and constraints applied to seeing weather patterns from more than 500 miles away (as a miniscule layer on a flat horizon). I assume any patterns would have to be like Noctilucent clouds that exist in the mesosphere. Naturally they'd probably get very icy, but that sort of works for what I'm working with. I am somewhat worried about all that water dispersing into space.

Why there's this sort of weather is not important. Question is, what would happen to those clouds?

Alternatively this could be 100 miles, if that is more reasonable. This isn't exactly a hospitable planet, but for the sake of argument I'm comparing it to Earth.

Comment: I don't know about 500 miles, but here on Earth you *can* often see clouds 100 miles away. They only have to be about 2000 meters or 6000 feet above sea level, and that is not exceptionally high for a regular cloud.

Comment: Some place on the web there is a calculator that shows you horizon distance as a function of altitude and planet radius.   Then there's this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_height

Comment: I can see the possibility of how far away they could be, I'm just wondering what would actually happen to clouds so high in the atmosphere that they could be seen so far away